# How to configure SQL Server 2008 to send mail on backup fail?

Tags: sql-server-2008, email, transactions

there is a database server which get TRN backup each minute and a full backup on 15 minutes. is there any possible way to configure that SQL server send mail notification each time full backup run fail?

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming**, but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.

Comment: sorry I really didn't checked the topic.

Comment: A `transaction log backup` every minute can be justified but a `full backup` every 15 minutes is just a waste of resources. Do you know about `Differential Backups` ?